# Decrypt EMV certificate algorithm

Tags: certificate, rsa, javacard, emv

I am working on EMV technology and trying to decrypt ISSUER PUBLIC KEY CERTIFICATE.
As per my understanding about CA Certificate, certificate contain Issuer Public key inside it. CA authority keep data along with public key and encrypt this all with its PRIVATE KEY.

```
EMV BOOK 2 Table 6: Format of Data Recovered from Issuer Public Key Certificate,
```

Define certificate format. it means if I will decrypt the certificate from CA public key, we could get the data in the format specified in table -6.

On the internet I found BP-TOOL which doing this kind of activity and very similar what I want to get. sharing here BP-Tool example:-
DDA: Issuer Public Key Recovery

---

```
CA PK Modulus:
BE9E1FA5E9A803852999C4AB432DB28600DCD9DAB76DFAAA47355A0FE37B1508AC6BF38860D3C6C2E5B12A3CAAF2A7005A7241EBAA7771112C74CF9A0634652FBCA0E5980C54A64761EA101A114E0F0B5572ADD57D010B7C9C887E104CA4EE1272DA66D997B9A90B5A6D624AB6C57E73C8F919000EB5F684898EF8C3DBEFB330C62660BED88EA78E909AFF05F6DA627B
 Issuer's Public Key Certificate:
7F4C6034C33BF35BAFFF53F51C0F8A2B32C8FDE1D033DDB69DCA85C5B4797BD2F55BE970C026B75B76E9C17E8564111FDEB97B26E350F59F6C63C30B0BD80E33123DF73CF8F87B28D54D28E4D6284F44E6E61AD95826474EBF6C28796B9B222DF14194A539E92DB185D86D8EDDD8AA01ECBE93E0EC3F87383D879534FE0BD397D7D59FC6E37012258B894400EE715338
 ----------------------------------------
 Recovered Data:                6A02457896FF12170314EF01019001E04E4FC478A42241068E2C9CFDEE9D7450F48F812FA66CEFB8ECBE31DD3C26C3B8A3891B77C1AA2A5A7448B869B7213D36C341E9B71302ADF478F67537032C080186C44034B1801D7644B6EEFAEA566D7336A8C83F42B7992F28BF5EA6B9D14C05870AD4DBD8CDAB8771F65F83D800B353B11E1805C7E4529F261C16A38DE756BC
 Data Header:                   6A
 Data Format:                   02
 Issuer Identifier:             457896FF
 Certificate Expiration Date:           1217
 Certificate Serial Number:         0314EF
 Hash Algorithm Indicator:          01
 Issuer Public Key Algorithm Indicator:     01
 Issuer Public Key Length:          90
 Issuer Public Key Exponent Length:     01
 Issuer Public Key:             E04E4FC478A42241068E2C9CFDEE9D7450F48F812FA66CEFB8ECBE31DD3C26C3B8A3891B77C1AA2A5A7448B869B7213D36C341E9B71302ADF478F67537032C080186C44034B1801D7644B6EEFAEA566D7336A8C83F42B7992F28BF5EA6B9D14C05870AD4DBD8CDAB8771F65F
 Hash Result:                   83D800B353B11E1805C7E4529F261C16A38DE756
 Data Trailer:                  BC
```

I am looking for the algorithm used in this example. your any help would be a lot for me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Big Digit library which will enable you to view how the algorithm works if you plan to implement your own, or use it to perform the decryption for you. I got mine from [here](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html) and used it to create a decryption function for my EMV program. I just pass values to it and it gives me back the answer. There are examples in the link to help you get up to speed.

Comment: Is there any online tool for this purpose, actually we are facing problem while importing certificate in HSM. With help of tool I can identify , certificate is correct or not.. and then create my own tool.

Comment: If you want to specifically decrypt EMV certificates, you may not need any external tools to verify correctness of the certificate. The EMV standard specifies how a correctly decrypted certificate is supposed to look like, and no matter how you do it, there will be only one correct way to do it.. That is the most dependable source of validation you can get. What you can do is try out the samples and apply them to your scenario until they are able to give you the results as specified by the EMV standard.

Comment: As for the tools, there is this [BP-SIM](https://www.eftlab.com.au/index.php/products/babylon-payments-simulator-bp-sim) software from EFT lab, which simulates card transactions and gives you verbal output. This could be useful as you could compare your results against theirs.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at class IssuerPublicKeyCertificate from [javaemvreader](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader) project. It implements the recovery of issuer certificate.

Also take into account that a part of the issuer public key might be stored inside "Issuer Public Key Remainder" tag (0x92).